# How to synchronize ListCollectionView.CurrentItem and ListView.SelectedItem?

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding, collectionviewsource, listcollectionview

I have a ViewModel containing a `ListCollectionView` property, and a View containing a `ListView` control whose `ItemsSource` property is data bound to the ListCollectionView:

ViewModel:

```
    public ListCollectionView Pacientes { get; set; }

    public IRepositório<Paciente> RepositórioPacientes { get; set; }


    // CONSTRUTOR
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        RepositórioPacientes = new PacienteRepositorioFake();

        Pacientes = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(RepositórioPacientes.Items);
    }
}
```

View (heavily stripped down):

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Pacientes}"/>
    <Border DataContext="{Binding Pacientes/}">
        <!-- some controls displaying properties of Paciente entity -->
    </Border>
```

Note the `Binding Pacientes/` with a trailing slash, trying to bind to `Pacientes.CurrentItem`.

My intention here is to provide a Master/Detail view, with a ListView displaying all items, and a side panel displaying information from the Current/Selected Item.

The fact is: when I select an element in ListView, I would expect `Pacientes.CurrentItem` to be set, but apparently it is not!

So my question is: how can I set ListCollectionView.CurrentItem by selecting an item on a data bound ListBox?

Comment: Bind the the selected item of the control (ListView).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Pacientes}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

Comment: Wow, that simple... I've read a lot about all this stuff, and sure I've read about `IsSync...`, but I haven't figured out _that_ is the reason it is supposed to be used... My bad. Thanks a lot!